# Passing values to multiple tables from single form in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have two tables `user` and `treeview`. From my registration form I wanna pass data to these tables. For example I want to pass `username` to `user` table and `sponsor ID` to `treeview` table. For single table I use following convention.

```
public function add_user()
{
    $data=array(
        'user_name'=>$this->input->post('fullname'),
        'sponsor_id'=>$this->input->post('sponsor_id'),
    );
    $this->db->insert('user',$data);
}
```

For multiple table what should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about:

```
public function add_user()
{
    $data1 = array('user_name' => $this->input->post('fullname'));
    $data2 = array('sponsor_id' => $this->input->post('sponsor_id'));
    $this->db->insert('user', $data1);
    $this->db->insert('treeview', $data2);
}
```

Don't forget to clean the data before inserting it into the db.